# Add context to django userena view

Tags: python, django

Very simple question need a very simple solution. I need to add extra context to a profile view called profile_detail while still including the original context. Here is the userena view.

```
def profile_detail(request, username,
    template_name=userena_settings.USERENA_PROFILE_DETAIL_TEMPLATE,
    extra_context=None, **kwargs):
    .........................
    .........................
    user = get_object_or_404(User,
                             username__iexact=username)

    profile_model = get_profile_model()
    try:
        profile = user.get_profile()
    except profile_model.DoesNotExist:
        profile = profile_model.objects.create(user=user)

    if not profile.can_view_profile(request.user):
        return HttpResponseForbidden(_("You don't have permission to view this profile."))
    if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['profile'] = user.get_profile()
    extra_context['hide_email'] = userena_settings.USERENA_HIDE_EMAIL
    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                            extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

I was told this would work. First I imported the userena view as `userena_views`. Then I tried to create my context, then send the request using the userena view and also change my urls to point to this view.

```
def profileview(request,username):
    user=User.objects.get(username=username)
    usergigs=Gig.objects.filter(user.id)
    extra_context['usergig']=usergigs
    return userena_views.profile_detail(request)
```

This didn't work, is this the right way? Is there an elegant way to do it? Or is my only option to copy the view into my views and edit from there?

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your code like this ?

```
def profileview(request,username):
    user=User.objects.get(username=username)
    usergigs=Gig.objects.filter(user.id)
    extra_context['usergig']=usergigs
    return userena_views.profile_detail(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```