# Override django userena views

Tags: django, django-views

I know there is a plethora of questions related to this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763290/add-context-to-django-userena-view), but I does not seem to help.

My question is simple, given [this function signature](http://pythonhosted.org/django-userena/api/views.html#profile-detail), how do I override the view `profile_detail`? I seem to be doing everything exactly as both resources say, but my templates are still not receiving the extra context. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
# This overrides and extends userena's view named 'profile_detail'.
def profileDetailView(request, username):
    # Do some logic, etc. 
    foo_list = Some.objects.filter(id=username)
    extra_context = {'foo_list': foo_list}
    # I have also tried the following for extra_context:
    extra_context['foo_list'] = foo_list
    return userena_views.profile_detail(request, username, template_name='userena/profile_detail.html',
                                        extra_context=extra_context)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have my URL's correct, as it is loading my views without error. Also, I have tested through the shell to create `foo_list` by import objects - it worked. I have also done a test to make sure the username being passed in actually results in an object being found. Thus - it seems like the only problem could be in the `extra_context`, at least I hope! Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: File structure Request

```
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └─
│   │   └── js
│   ├── test.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── media
├── templates
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── base_site.html
│   ├── base_site.html
│   ├── errors
│   │   └── not_authorized.html
│   └── userena
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── base_userena.html
│       ├── profile_detail.html
│       ├── profile_details.html
│       └── signup_form.html
└── utils


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/username/project/project/templates',
)
```

Comment: Have you tried pointing `template_name` to a custom template instead of userena's?

Comment: Yes - I have a directory in my templates directory named 'userena'. This directory contains my overrides for userena. In my URLs I direct to the the view containing the overridden views/templates, and then I include the default ones.

Comment: Can you show your project's file tree as well as your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: I just edited my question with this information. I removed all of my applications and most of the files for brevity, but you still see the structure and the template directory. Note - I changed the file names to a unique name (and changed the template name), it properly rendered my view, but still didn't have the context...strange.

Comment: Gahh! Just solved it! For anyone coming here with this problem, the two links in my question were 100% correct, as well as all of the code in my override view. The problem was from my URLConf looking in the wrong place - something I thought a test was covering, thanks the help again Paulo!